# How to understand "a natural spin-1/2 representation of the point-group action of $g$"?

Tags: symmetry, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

I learn from Ref[1] that a natural spin-1/2 representation of the point-group operation of $\mathit{g}$ can be defined as $$\begin{align}v_g=\exp(-i\theta_g\hat{\pmb{n}}_g\cdot\pmb{\sigma}/2) 
,\tag 1\end{align}$$ where $\mathit{g}$ is any point-group operation parametrized by the rotation angle $\theta_g$ and the axis $\hat{\pmb{n}}_g$, and $\pmb{\sigma}=(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ is the vector of Pauli matrices. Since inversion symmetry $I$ leaves spin invariant, any mirror operation $M$ can be regarded as a two-fold rotation so that  $\theta_g=\pi$ and $\hat{\pmb{n}}_g$ is the normal direction of $M$.

*I'm confused because there is a matrix on the exponential term. I wonder how to convert it into ordinary matrix form in mathematics.*

---

As far as I know, if the basis functions are spin-up and spin-down, then the spin-1/2 representation for the point group can be written as
$$\begin{align}
v_g=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\frac{\theta_g}{2}-in\sin\frac{\theta_g}{2} & -i(l-im)\sin\frac{\theta_g}{2} \\
-i(l+im)\sin\frac{\theta_g}{2} & \cos\frac{\theta_g}{2}+in\sin\frac{\theta_g}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}, \tag 2
\end{align}$$where $l, m, n$ are the direction cosine between the $\hat{\pmb{n}}_g$ and $\hat{\pmb{x}}, \hat{\pmb{y}}, \hat{\pmb{z}}$ axes, respectively.

For example, a two-fold rotation about the $\hat{\pmb{z}}$ axis is written as
$$v_{C_{2z}}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-i\pi/2} & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\pi/2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
satisfying $v_{C_{2z}}^2=-1$. I can't see the mathematical connection between equation (1) and equation (2), which are essentially the same matrix.

[1] Khalaf E, Po H C, Vishwanath A, et al. Symmetry indicators and anomalous surface states of topological crystalline insulators[J]. Physical Review X, 2018, 8(3): 031070.
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.031070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard formula for exponentiating a Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector), in your language, is just
$$
(2)= {\mathbb I} \cos \frac{\theta_g}{2} -i(l\sigma_x+m\sigma_y+ n\sigma_z) \sin\frac{\theta_g}{2} = \exp (-i\hat{\pmb{n}}_g\cdot\pmb{\sigma} ~~ \theta_g/2 )=(1).
$$

Comment: Thanks！The detailed derivation in Wikipedia is really helpful.